# Bootstrap include php inside modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to insert a php script that gets values for a select element into a modal. But The php script works and gets the right info. But whenever i try and load the script into the modal like so:

```
<?php include 'script.php' ?>
```

My modal wont show up. These are my files:

Index.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="upload" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Tilføj en note</h4>
    </div>
    <form action="scripts/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Navn:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Navn på note..">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Fag:</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <?php include 'scripts/getClasses.php'; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Beskrivelse:</label>
        <textarea name="description" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
      <label for="file">Vælg fil:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

scripts/getClasses.php

```
<?php
    require 'funcs.php';
    $function = new functions;
    $class = $function->getClasses();

    $numclasses = count($class);
    for($i=0;$i<$numclasses;$i++)
    {
        $id = $class[$i]['id'];
        $name = $class[$i]['name'];

        echo "<option value='".$id."'>".$name."</option>";
    }
?>
```

snippet of funcs.php

```
public function getClasses()
        //Function that gets all the classes. Used when user adds a new note.
        {
            require 'connect.php';
            $count = 0;
            $q = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM classes ORDER BY name ASC');
            $q->execute();
            while($row = $q->fetch())
            {
                $results[$count]['id'] = $row['id'];
                $results[$count]['name'] = $row['name'];
                $count++;
            }

            return $results;
        }
```

Comment: And where exactly is `<?php include 'script.php' ?>` in these files?

Comment: First file. Around the middle part:                          <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Fag:</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <?php include 'scripts/getClasses.php'; ?>
        </select>
      </div>

Comment: What happens when you try to use `require` instead of `include`?

Comment: Same thing. The modal is not popping up.

Comment: All of your require paths are relative, so one of those require commands are probably breaking. You can use your Apache logs to determine which one is actually breaking. You can also fix your require commands by using absolute paths or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or something similar

Comment: Hmm. That include is the second include in the index file. The second one works fine. But I tried your suggestion and changed the line to: include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/getClasses.php'; But still nothing.

Comment: You have more `require` commands in getClasses.php and funcs.php. Fix those too.

Comment: hello is there any success?